# How can I make a TextBox that only accepts numbers from 30 to 250

Tags: vb.net

How can I make a TextBox that only accepts numbers from 30 to 250 in VB.Net 2010. I need to store the value in an Integer so that I can use it in a calculation.

```
Dim x As String = textbox1
Dim y As Integer

y = Cint(textbox1)

If x <= 29 then
Msg("cant accept")
Textbox1 = ""
End if
```

Comment: Are you sure you're able to compile your code ? How do you want to set TextBox1 object to string and integer variables, how are you setting the textbox to empty string ? You should use Text property instead of the textBox object itself.

Comment: Step 1: Use NumericUpDown instead of a TextBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use NumericUpDown control instead of TextBox, but if you want to use TextBox try this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    Dim int As Integer = 0
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, int) Then
        MessageBox.Show("You should enter a number")
        TextBox1.Clear()
        Return
    End If

    If int < 30 OrElse int > 150 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You should enter a number between 30 and 150")
        TextBox1.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Leave` event is not for validation.

Comment: I saw your answer and it's better than mine ^_^
I have never seen the Validating event. Thanks, I learned something new :)

Comment: Can you give me an example code if I use the numericUpDown. Tahnkyou 

Comment: @Draregpogi with the numeric up down all you do is set the minimum and maximum on the control, then you get the selected value using `numericUpDown.Value`, all the validation is done for you :)

Answer (score 6):

Validate the contents of the control in the `Validating` event handler and cancel the event if it fails.  That will prevent the control losing focus if it contains invalid text.  You can then use the contents with confidence later, with `CInt` or `Convert.ToInt32`.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    Dim number As Integer

    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, number) OrElse
       number < 30 OrElse
       number > 250 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter an integer from 30 to 250.",
                        "Invalid Input",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        'Don't let the control lose focus.
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```